# Constructor not defined: [myservice.listValues].<Constructor>(String, String) apex salesforce

Tags: methods, constructor, salesforce

I need to use webservice to get some values. I  generated apex class from wsdl , in that class I get

```
public class myService{
    public myService.userInfo[] listValues(Long userId,String userName) {

    ...
    }
}
```

I need to pass parameters and to get some values
So I wrote this

```
myservice.listValues myObj = new  myservice.listValues('456','myName');
```

and I got this error:

```
Constructor not defined: [myservice.listValues].<Constructor>(String, String)
```

thanks

Comment: listValues is a method and you are trying to use it as a class.

Comment: myservice.listValues myObj = new  myservice().listValues('456','myName');

Answer (score 1):

Moti Korets is correct, you need to instantiate the class first and then call the method on the instance.  You should instead be doing it like

```
myService srv = new myService();
srv.listValues(456,'myName');
```